# How can i check if the List Length is smaller than the trackBar1.Value by 1 each time?

Tags: c#, winforms

In the Form1 pictureBox scroll event i did:

```
private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (wireObjectAnimation1.wocl.Count < trackBar1.Value && 
        }
```

For example lets say that the List wocl contain 2 indexs so the List Count is 2.
And the trackBar1.Value is now on 3.
So i need to check this condiations:

1. If the List Length is smaller by 1 each time from the trackBar1.Value enabled a button.
2. If the List Length is smaller by more then 1 from the trackBar1.Value disable a button.

Number 2 is for example: If the List Count is 2 and i moved the trackBar.Value to 7 so the difference is 5 meaning the button should be disable. Only if the difference between the List Count and the trackBar1.Value is by 1 enable true the button.

So when i move the trackBar each time to the right by one enable true the button.
If i jumped/moved the trackBar a once from the last position to the right by more then one disable the button.

How can i check all this ?

** Thats why my code is not complete , i need to check if the List Count is small by 1 from the trackBar1.Value but also to check that it smaller by 1 and not only smaller.

Comment: `wireObjectAnimation1.wocl.Count == trackBar1.Value - 1`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I'd say

```
private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      if (wireObjectAnimation1.wocl.Count == trackBar1.Value - 1)
            //Enable button
      else
            //Disable button  
}
```

I'm assuming that you want it disabled for every other case when the 'if' conditional isn't true.